# pythonic way to call multiple callbacks

Tags: python, python-2.x

Subclass constructor has a param that takes a callback function as an argument. I would like to insert another custom function for the callback within my subclass constructor so that I can call multiple callbacks. Is there an easy way to do this without modifying the callbacks or writing some special code to loops through all callbacks in the Base class.

```
class Base:
    def __init__(callback=None):
       if callback: callback()

class Subclass(Base):
    def __init__(callback=None):
       def another_callback(...):
           print "another_callback"

       super(Base, self).__init__(callback)
```

example use:

```
def a_callback(...):
   print "a_callback"

x = Subclass(callback=a_callback)
```

The above should print (order doesn't matter)
"a_callback"
"another_callback"

Comment: It wouldn't be sufficient to just wrap the calls to the callback in a lambda that calls them both?

Comment: Please can you update your question with properly formatted python code. It is difficult to understand what is happening, especially in `Subclass`.

Comment: I updated Subclass. Right now it just passes callback argument, but I would like to pass along some object that when invoked would call both "a_callback" and "another_callback"

Comment: @Carcigenicate - can you give an example

Comment: @mayas_mom Something like `callback = lambda: callback(); another_callback()`

Answer (score 0):

I think this code does what you want.

I have had to modify your original code so that:

- it compiles
- Subclass inherits from Base
- it is python 3 code since that is the version I have to hand

---

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, callback=None):
        if callback: callback()

class Subclass(Base):
    def __init__(self, callback=None):
        def another_callback():
            if callback: callback()
            print("another_callback")

        super().__init__(another_callback)

def a_callback():
    print("a_callback")

def b_callback():
    print("b_callback")

x = Subclass(callback=a_callback)
y = Subclass(callback=b_callback)
```

Output:

```
a_callback
another_callback
b_callback
another_callback
```

The output shows that each instance of `Subclass` can call any given callback as well as the local function in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Just call it in the subclass' `__init__()` *before* calling the super class' `__init__()`—which works in both Python 2 and 3 as long as the base class is "new-style" (directly or indirectly has `object` as one of its base classes...the default in Python 3.x).

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, callback=None):
       if callback: callback()


class Subclass(Base):
    def __init__(self, callback=None):
        def another_callback():
           print('another_callback')

        another_callback()  # Just call it.
        super(Subclass, self).__init__(callback)


def a_callback():
   print('a_callback')

x = Subclass(callback=a_callback)
```

Output:

```
another_callback
a_callback
```